# Output volume locked with clients - PulseAudio

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, volume-control

When I change the volume inside a pulse-audio client like VLC , the output volume in the `pavucontrol->Output Device->Built-in Audio analog Stereo` gets adjusted accordingly.So when I increase the volume inside VLC , the effect gets boosted and increases dramatically which is too loud even in 50% volume and vice versa.

Furthermore `Volume up` and `Volume down` system shortcuts increase the VLC volume beside increasing the system's. Looks like they're kind of locked to each other.

I use `PulseAudio` 11.1 in ubuntu bionic.

How can I unlock that?